# how to create an empty database

Tags: sqlite

I want to create an empty database for SQLite.
I use cmd and I write the code below to create it:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

but I can't see any database in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow configuring things like the page size, the database file is not created until you actually write to it, i.e., `CREATE TABLE ...`, or simply `PRAGMA user_version = 0`.